# Load more same category div

Tags: jquery

On selecting a particular category and click on load more, then only the selected category should load. For Ex: if I selected "Red" and click, the only Red category div should load.

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/op1mubgq/1/)

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
            $('#colorselector').change(function(){
                $('.colors').hide();
                $('.' + $('#colorselector').val()).slice(0, 2).show();
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.' + $('#colorselector').val() + ':hidden').slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                    if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
                        $('.colors').hide();
                        $('.colors').slice(0, 2).show();
                        $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                    }
         
                });
                $("#loadMore").fadeIn('slow');
            });
         
             $(".colors").slice(0, 2).show();
             $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $(".colors:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                 if ($(".colors:hidden").length == 0) {
                     $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                 }
             });
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - I have updated the code, so all use cases work properly -

```js
$(function () {
    $('#colorselector').change(function () {
        $('.colors').hide();
        if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
            $('.colors').slice(0, 2).show();        
        } else {
            $('.' + $('#colorselector').val()).slice(0, 2).show();
        }
        $("#loadMore").fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $(".colors").slice(0, 2).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
            $(".colors:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('.' + $('#colorselector').val() + ':hidden').slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        }
        if ($(".colors:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
  background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}

.output {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em; 
}
.colors {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.red {
  background: #c04;
} 
.yellow {
  color: #000;
  background: #f5e000;
} 
.blue {
  background: #079;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="wrapper" for="states">This label is stacked above the select</label>

      <div class="button dropdown">
         <select id="colorselector">
            <option value="all" selected="">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="output">
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

<s>Just deregister the click event before registering, it should do the trick -</s>

```
$("#loadMore").off('click');
```

Final code looks like -

```js
$(function() {
            $('#colorselector').change(function(){
                $('.colors').hide();
                $('.' + $('#colorselector').val()).slice(0, 2).show();
                $("#loadMore").off('click'); // Code added here
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.' + $('#colorselector').val() + ':hidden').slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                    if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
                        $('.colors').hide();
                        $('.colors').slice(0, 2).show();
                        $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                    }
         
                });
                $("#loadMore").fadeIn('slow');
            });
         
             $(".colors").slice(0, 2).show();
             $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $(".colors:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                 if ($(".colors:hidden").length == 0) {
                     $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                 }
             });
         });
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
  background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}

.output {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em; 
}
.colors {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.red {
  background: #c04;
} 
.yellow {
  color: #000;
  background: #f5e000;
} 
.blue {
  background: #079;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="wrapper" for="states">This label is stacked above the select</label>

      <div class="button dropdown">
         <select id="colorselector">
            <option value="all" selected="">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="output">
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Comment: Hi, Nikhil, thanks for the above code, there is one thing, after selecting category (ex. red), then if I select the 'All' category, then Load more button disssapear.

Comment: @AdamPavlov, I have changed the code a bit so it works.

Comment: Oh yes, this is that. Thanks, Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

here you need take value from select and take div with this value

```
$(function() {
            $('#colorselector').change(function(){
                $('.colors').hide();
                $('.' + $('#colorselector').val()).slice(0, 2).show();
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.' + $('#colorselector').val() + ':hidden').slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                    if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
                        $('.colors').hide();
                        $('.colors').slice(0, 2).show();
                        $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                    }
         
                });
                $("#loadMore").fadeIn('slow');
            });
         
             $(".colors").slice(0, 2).show();
             $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var color = $('#colorselector').val();
                 $(".colors."+color+":hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                 if ($(".colors:hidden").length == 0) {
                     $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                 }
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and show divs having particular color class like this

```
$(".output").children().hide().filter("."+$('#colorselector').val()).show();
```

Get the dropdown color value from `$('#colorselector').val()` and filter based on the same

Run the code below to see it in action

```js
$(function() {
            $('#colorselector').change(function(){
                $('.colors').hide();
                $('.' + $('#colorselector').val()).slice(0, 2).show();
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.' + $('#colorselector').val() + ':hidden').slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                    if (($('#colorselector').val() === "all")) {
                        $('.colors').hide();
                        $('.colors').slice(0, 2).show();
                        $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                    }
         
                });
                $("#loadMore").fadeIn('slow');
            });
         
             $(".colors").slice(0, 2).show();
             $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 if($('#colorselector').val() == "all"){
                 $(".output").children().hide().filter("."+"colors").show();
                 }
                 else{
                 $(".output").children().hide().filter("."+$('#colorselector').val()).show();
                 }
                 
                 //$(".colors:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
                 //if ($(".colors:hidden").length == 0) {
                     //$("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
                 //}
             });
         });
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
  background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}

.output {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em; 
}
.colors {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.red {
  background: #c04;
} 
.yellow {
  color: #000;
  background: #f5e000;
} 
.blue {
  background: #079;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="wrapper" for="states">This label is stacked above the select</label>

      <div class="button dropdown">
         <select id="colorselector">
            <option value="all" selected="">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="output">
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors red">  “Good artists copy, great artists steal” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div class="colors yellow"> “Art is the lie that enables us to realize the truth” Pablo Picasso</div>
         <div  class="colors blue"> “If I don't have red, I use blue” Pablo Picasso</div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ta6o7dsn/